# dig: couldn't get address for 'ns2.bluedental.pl': not found. Linux DNS server

Tags: debian, bind

I have my own DNS server.

Web browsers shows `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` for my sites.

My external IP is `37.190.144.15`

For example I have `cloud.bluedental.pl` domain.

When I type `dig cloud.bluedental.pl`  from server, everything works

But when I make `dig cloud.bluedental.pl` from external network I got `NXDOMAIN` Error.

When I check `dig cloud.bluedental.pl @37.190.144.15` everything works again.

But if I type `dig cloud.bluedental.pl @ns2.bluedental.pl`, the output is: `dig: couldn't get address for 'ns2.bluedental.pl': not found`

**cloud.bluedental.pl bind config file:**

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA cloud.bluedental.pl. marcin.bluedental.pl ( 2019071000 10800 15 604800 10800 )
@ IN NS ns2.bluedental.pl.
ns2 IN A 37.190.144.15
@ IN A 37.190.144.15
www IN A 37.190.144.15
```

**cloud.bluedental.pl zone:**

```
zone "cloud.bluedental.pl" IN {
    type master;
    allow-transfer {none;};
    file "/var/named/dns.cloud.bluedental.pl.conf";
};
```

**Bind options:**

```
acl mynetwork {
    172.19.0.0/10;
    192.168.1.0/24;
    localhost;
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";


    allow-recursion { mynetwork; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-update { none; };

    forwarders {
             8.8.8.8;
             84.200.69.80;
             8.26.56.26;
    };

    dnssec-validation auto;
    version "Bluedental DNS2 server";
    hostname none;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    server-id none;
};
```

Two weeks ago these configurations worked well for many months. I don't know why now it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is answering *authoritatively* for `bluedental.pl`, but it's not an authoritative DNS server for the domain on the parent `.pl` zone.

Your server answers:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
bluedental.pl.          86400   IN      NS      ns2.bluedental.pl.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.bluedental.pl.      86400   IN      A       37.190.144.15

;; SERVER: 37.190.144.15#53(37.190.144.15)
```

But the parent (`c-dns.pl`) has `nazwa.pl`, which is also your *registrar*:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
bluedental.pl.          86400   IN      NS      ns1.nazwa.pl.
bluedental.pl.          86400   IN      NS      ns2.nazwa.pl.
bluedental.pl.          86400   IN      NS      ns3.nazwa.pl.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.nazwa.pl.           86400   IN      A       77.55.125.10
ns2.nazwa.pl.           86400   IN      A       77.55.126.10
ns3.nazwa.pl.           86400   IN      A       77.55.127.10

;; SERVER: 93.190.128.146#53(93.190.128.146)
```

You have two options:

- Configure your DNS records on Nazwa.pl's DNS system: there's probably some web-based tool you can use to add the records `@ IN A 37.190.144.15` & `www IN A 37.190.144.15`.
- Change your nameservers to somewhere else. According to both IANA [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements) and [Terms and conditions concerning the [.pl] Domain Name](https://www.dns.pl/en/registration_domain_pl/technical_conditions) **you need at least two name servers** that are on topologically separate networks. Your current single server configuration isn't compatible with that!

I'd recommend using the name servers from your registrar until you have stronger experience with DNS.

Comment: "Change your nameservers to somewhere else. According to both IANA" Here it is not what IANA wants for the delegation, but what the `.pl` registry requires, or not. For example, some registries require nameserver to be out of band registered with them (like `.dk`)  or requires them to be on the country soil. So it is really the specific registry rules that needs to be reviewed. Besides that I strongly agree with "I'd recommend using the name servers from your registrar until you have stronger experience with DNS."

Comment: "that are on topologically separate networks" I doubt a lot of registries check AS numbers and AS paths, so while everything say that it is more wishful thinking. It is also technically a little wrong, because an anycasted IP address, when done properly, from only one AS and hence one IP address, can surely be better than 5 nameservers on 5 different IP addresses but each behind one and only one transit provider and all in the same POP.